Read binary bytes object from Shapely to_wkb into QGIS
I've a typical case of data exported using shapely to_wkb with hex=False option. screenshot of data as shown in WKBgeom below (without SRID here).

I am trying to load the data into QGIS via a virtual layer. The column loads as a blob. However unable to do so with GeomFromEWKB function via query.
I've tried hex() wrapping the column but it returns only 0102 dropping the rest of it. I've tried for both SRID coded and SRID excluded binary representations and only 0102 is returned irrespective of SRID.
I used python to produce hex string representation of the data, which works out of the box using GeomFromEWKB.
I've tried looking in to QGIS / spatialite list of functions, but nothing seems to address the problem. eg: encode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055849/how-can-i-print-bytea-data-as-a-hexadecimal-string-in-postgresql-pgadmin-iii, may be convert_bytes_to_hex https://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/3.0/db/ded/pgsql2shp-core_8c_a3e18a43c50fdcc5f41b2d32c09c5b6a5.html
I am looking for something like from QGIS geometry handling eg: fromWkb(wkb bytes) or some other alternative. Python in between isn't of much help as there is limit of hex string length due to DB constraints.

What is the data provider, i.e., where is the exported data being stored so it can be fed to QGIS?

A typical parquet file (not to be confused with geoparquet) with schema like "optional binary field_id=-1 WKBgeom;". Wondering if this should be independent of the source.
